# Error: Cannot find module 'jasmine-allure-reporter'

Tags: protractor

I m new in using protractor for testing. I want to extract reports with jasmine-allure-report module.

I already run some tests using protractor with visual studio code.
I install it in my ubuntu PC following the instructions from https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-allure-reporter.

When I run the command `protractor ./conf/conf.js` I get the error :

**Error: Error: Cannot find module `jasmine-allure-reporter`**

When I run the command `npm list -g jasmine-allure-reporter` I get that :

```
/usr/local/lib

├── jasmine-allure-reporter@1.0.2 

├─┬ npm@6.13.7

│ └── jasmine-allure-reporter@1.0.2 

└─┬ protractor@5.4.2

  └── jasmine-allure-reporter@1.0.2
```

Does anyone knows why happen that?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your package.json here

Answer (score 0):

Install jasmine-allure-reporter in your project root directory using the below command.

```
npm i --save jasmine-allure-reporter
```